# VSCode Prettier Format on Save messes up formatting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Been using VSCode Prettier format on save feature for a while.

Lately is CONSTANTLY makes mistakes and misformats Javascript.

For example:

`const foo = 123`

[save]

`const foo = 1;23`

I've disabled it for now, but is there some way to make this not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think that there is a way to fix this. I also use Prettier on my projects, and **YES** sometimes it is annoying. I do not know if there are such specific configurations to solve your issue, but you cannot do anything else, except uninstalling or disabling the extension.

> Remember, even if you do not choose to "prettify" your code *on save*, it will do it somewhen and the only option is to disable it.

**UPDATE 03-05-2020**

---

You can use the comment `// prettier-ignore` in your files or nodes of code to ignore `Prettier` formatting.

Reference & example: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: Yup very annoying. Had a live code presentation. The demo was broken. Turned out it was Prettier inserting a rough semi-colon. 

Comment: It is a nice tool though. I use it for most of my projects.